# Unable to disable concurrent GC in .NET 4 ASP.NET w/ Cassini? "gcConcurrent" does not work

Tags: asp.net, .net, garbage-collection

According to all the MSDN docs I can find, to disable Concurrent GC, you add this to your application config:

```
<runtime>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

However, I have a .NET 4 ASP.NET app that I am running though VS2010 using Cassini (ASP.NET Development Server). Whether I specify `enabled="true"` or `enabled="false"` either way, making a call to `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification()` throws the exception:

> This API is not available when the concurrent GC is enabled.

I have tried it running with and without debug, and everything fails the same way.
Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: I believe this setting is ignored by Cassini, and is only used by IIS. See rick schott's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use IIS Express, it's free and a much more capable web server than Cassini.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I forgot I even had it installed. Interestingly, the web.config setting DOES work with IIS Express but NOT with Cassini. Since its a .NET runtime option, I'm curious why the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the relevant setting to Cassini's own config file appears to work.